# golang regexp break after first match

Tags: regex, go

I have the following go code:

```
s := `prefix<b>Group ID:</b><br/>
G123<br/>temporary<br/>suffix`

re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?s)(.*)<b>Group ID:</b><br/>(.*)<br/>(.*)`)

m := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(s, -1)
fmt.Println(m[0][2])
```

playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/hz2kg7Pe2Z

The above program prints `\nG123<br/>temporary` because the last/second `<br/>` after the pattern is matched, as per the regex. Is there a way to get the first `<br/>` to be matched so that the output will be, just: `G123`. In addition to the first br match, the newline/whitespace in the beginning should also be stripped. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Use `.*?` instead of the `.*` instead of the first two `.*`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. I was about to ping you as you have already answered some of my regex questions but could not find such an option in stackoverflow.

Comment: I think my first comment is a bit corrupt, I meant to say: *Use `.*?` (lazy quantifier) instead of the first two `.*`*.

Comment: No worries. I got it working based on the answer in the duplicate link. Thanks for your help.